# Which version of TCP are used in LTE network?

Tags: communication

In many papers, they said the performance of TCP is not good in wireless network. But I didn't feel it when using LTE network. So how did they solve it in LTE net.?

Answer (score 1):

There are different versions with minor differences.

Take a look at this paper http://ijarcet.org/wp-content/uploads/IJARCET-VOL-5-ISSUE-7-2240-2242.pdf

> In this paper, we review about various versions of Transmission
>   Control Protocol (TCP) in LTE networks. There are various versions of
>   TCP available with minor modifications, out of which we have tried to
>   list out many. Each version is better than the other in one way or the
>   other. A lot of research has been performed so far in order to
>   implement TCP in 4G for congestion control. Future scope of this paper
>   is to implement TCP in a better form such that it gives better
>   performance in 4G. Various versions of TCP can be combined together to
>   perform this task or research can be done to implement altogether a
>   new version of TCP.